# Conditional formatting with OR function

Tags: excel, function, pattern-matching, conditional-formatting

What I need is to color cells background if they match one of various given strings.

In my case this will be Column A containing values A1 = 1.08, A2 = 2.08 (second day of August, etc.)

What I'm trying to do is to change the background color of all weekend days by just specifying it like that:

Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

And I'm trying to use the OR() function, which, however, doesn't seem to be working (on the range of my values) like that: =OR("1.08";"2.08";"9.08";"10.08" ...).

What works for me is:
Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Format only cells that contain > Cell Value > equal to > ... (but in this case I'd have to make many rules that have the same formatting which is not really what I'm into, but for different values.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go.

```
Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use formula to determine which cells to 
format > formula =OR(A1 = 1.08,A1 = 2.08,A1 = 9.08,A1 = 10.08)
```

and select the desired format colour

Then Again

```
Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > Applies to
```

There give the range of selection you want to apply this formula. 
Done!!

Comment: It's a strictly brute-force solution which isn't really what anybody would like to implement.

Comment: I use this solutions with string values, and it works as well. Here is my formula: *=OR(C5 = "ok - Dropbox"; C5 = "(no need)")*  Whereever cells have the one or the other string content, I let the text appear green in order to see "okay, no action needed".

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the values to be strings? If the values were actual **dates** then you can format **any** weekend date with a simple formula in conditional formatting:

`=WEEKDAY(A1,2)>5`

You can retain the "look" of the data by formatting your dates with custom format

`d.mm`

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do (Office 2003 :(  ) to sidestep not being able to use an OR statement in a conditional format is to add a new hidden column, put the OR statements in those cells, and then link the formatting of the first cell off of whether the hidden cell's value is TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: This is very clever. I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

My trick is always

`=OR(Address(row(),Column())="1.08,Address(row(),Column())="2.08)`

A bit of a stretch but works.